# public properties when using React hooks

Tags: react-hooks

a start-up component can new a class and set values of some public properties in it to be used later in methods of same class.

What will be the equivalent of this in a hook component? Should these properties be added to a context and read from there? Is there a simpler option?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If this are constant properties, you can define consts inside or outside the component.

```
const noOfItems = 5

const Comp = () => {
  const items = 'cats'
  
  return (
    <div>{noOfItems} {items }></div>
  )
}
```

If the values can change, and changing them causes re-render, then you should use `useState` or `useReducer`:

```
const Comp = ({ items }) => {
  const [noOfItems, setNoOfItems] = useState(0)
  
  return (
    <>
      <div>{noOfItems} {items}></div>
      <button onClick={() => setNoOfItems(x => x + 1)}>
        Add Items
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

And if it's something you wish to mutate, but changing it won't cause re-render, you can do so with `useRef`:

```
const Comp = ({ items, doSomething }) => {
  const [noOfItems, setNoOfItems] = useState(0)
  const fn = useRef() // fn would be preserved between renders, and mutating it won't cause re-renders

  useEffect(() => {
    fn.current = doSomething // changing this won't cause a re-render
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    fn.current(noOfItems)
  }, [noOfItems])

  return (
    <>
      <div>{noOfItems} {items}></div>
      <button onClick={() => setNoOfItems(x => x + 1)}>
        Add Items
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Although not public, you can can also keep variables (and consts) inside a closure - for example `useEffect`, as long as it's not invoked again:

```
const Comp = ({ items }) => {
  const [noOfItems, setNoOfItems] = useState(0)

  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => /* do something */) // the interval would preserved in the closure at it ins't called again

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, [])

  return (
    <>
      <div>{noOfItems} {items}></div>
      <button onClick={() => setNoOfItems(x => x + 1)}>
        Add Items
      </button>
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: I missing the part of setting the value in a start-up component (other module). Any relation to Oded Drori that managed Bagir Jerusalem?:-)

Comment: Set it as the initial value of the state if you're going to change it. Nope - no relationship :)